# problem with linkify in android app

Tags: android, linkify

I have a phone number in a `text view` (thats the only thing I have there). I am using :

```
Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.ALL);
```

However, the phone number is not being recognized by `linkify`. The number is of the format: 
 `(123) 456-7890`. I have also tried `1234567890` and `123.456.7890`. Nothing works. Any help ?

thanks.

Comment: @Venky :checked and updated your answer. thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your XML file of your Text View add an attribute `android:phoneNumber="true"`

Try this in the Click of the Text View :

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("tel:"
                + your_phone_number)));
```

Automatically the Text will have the property of Phone number.

Comment: @Ahsan After click in text View it should opens the Dialer right?

Comment: we need to set another attribute as well. editing your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying something that is custom refer to this doc

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/wikinotes-linkify.html

it will help you.

Comment: :this is not custom, I am trying to get a phone number detected !